# Segregate even and odd nodes in a Singly Linked List

Tags: singly-linked-list

I am trying to modify the linked list such that all even numbers appear before all the odd numbers in the modified linked list. Also, keep the order of even and odd numbers same.

Below code works:

```
 void segregateEvenOdd() 
{   
    if(head==null) return;
    Node temp=head,evenStart=null,evenEnd=null,oddStart=null,oddEnd=null;

    while(temp!=null){
        if(temp.data%2==0){
            if(evenStart==null){
                evenStart=temp;
                //evenStart.next=null;
                evenEnd=evenStart;
            }
            else{
                evenEnd.next=temp;
                evenEnd=evenEnd.next;
            //  evenEnd.next=null;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(oddStart==null){
                oddStart=temp;
                //oddStart.next=null;
                oddEnd=oddStart;

            }
            else{
                oddEnd.next=temp;
                oddEnd=oddEnd.next;
                //oddEnd.next=null;
            }
        }
        temp=temp.next;
    }

    if(oddStart==null || evenStart==null) return;

    evenEnd.next=oddStart;
    oddEnd.next=null;
    head=evenStart;
}
```

But when I uncomment the commented code, it doesn't work.
I am not able to understand this behavior.
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `evenStart, evenEnd, oddStart, oddEnd` are just references which at starting are pointing to `null` but when it encounters first element(suppose `Odd`), then following code will run

```
if(oddStart==null){
   oddStart=temp;
   oddStart.next=null;
   oddEnd=oddStart;
}
```

Here, in second line `oddStart.next=null`, it will not only change the `next` of `oddStart` but will also change the `next` of `temp` too. Due to which, if you uncomment everything your code will run the loop only once(because in first time `temp` next node will point to `null`).

Same case applies to all comments. You can `print` `temp.data` in loop to verify above fact.

Comment: @four So, were you able to figure out entirely why uncommenting didn't work for you. I explained just 1 scenario.